# Tapestry : onEvent on textfield

Tags: textfield, tapestry, mixins

I want to create a mixin onEvent on the textfield.
I follow this example :

http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/oneventdemo.

I don't have any errors, but it doesn't work.
When I change a value, it nothing happens.

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tapestry mixins you create have to be in the ".mixins" package of your application.

Comment: Yes, I found a few minutes ago, now I have another problem. Thank you.